# MVC 4 VB Additional view data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to find help for this problem has taken me to a whole new one: complete lack of ressources, books and samples vor MVC 4 in VB.NET. I am having to choose between learn by experience (and the associated feeling of banging your head against a wall) or give it up and move to C# alltogether.

No company should ship a product if they are not willing to give it the same support as its sibling pruduct. They should drop VB for MVC completely or give us the means to learn it.

With that out of the way, here's my question. This line:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.UsersData(temp).Roles(Role))
```

Is a nice line of code. Works wonders. But How can I add a class to it, so I can change the style on my css files?

Well, it seems that this should do the trick:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.UsersData(temp).Roles(Role), New With {.class = "users-manage-check-box"})
```

But guess what, it doesn't. Ever. The result is the same.

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

And to be completely honest, I did come up with a solution. One that makes me feel dirty.

Looking at the output from that code, i see that the boxes classes are "check-box".

So what I've been doing is this:

```
@html.Raw(Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.UsersData(temp).Roles(Role), New With {.class = "users-manage-textbox"}).ToHtmlString.Replace("check-box", "user-manage-checkbox"))
```

This feels wrong. So wrong. And not only is it a sad piece of code, it introduces security risks, which I'll have to fix before my solution is out of the development phase.

Any clues on why the additional view data is not working as it should? Am I getting something wrong? Am I asking too much?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think EditorFor allows that. So you need to create a custom editor template yourself.

You can read more about creating custom templates [in this blog post](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html)

**Update:**

Take a look at the answer for this issue from [http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/223)

> > This behavior is by design.
>
> The overload that you are calling accepts an object parameter called
>   additionalViewData (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462).
>   The default implementation of EditorFor ignores this value. You would
>   have to write a custom editor template to be able to access that
>   information.

Comment: But books and samples all say it should work. I could quote some books but unless I'm getting something really wrong, that's what they say: you pass a new { @class="class-you-want} to set the class of the html tag.
There's even that @ trick in C#.

Comment: I believe the blog you provided is using AdditionalData for something else, but setting the class of the tag is definitely something it could be used for, again, if I'm not completely wrong.